# How to pass ArrayList set from java to jsp in Liferay 7

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I can't find any good working simple examples of passing ArrayList set values from java to jsp and ArrayList set values from jsp file to java, vice versa.

I have looked in different sites and tried but it is not working. I noticed they are all from previous versions of Liferay in which the syntax are different or functions that can't be found in Liferay 7.0. I would like to know how it is correctly implemented for Liferay 7 version.

Comment: I assume this is a follow up to your deleted earlier question. In this case, the question is way too broad. I'd recommend to start with a Liferay tutorial (you find them on https://dev.liferay.com/) and when done with it, come back with concrete questions, e.g. working code that needs to do just a little bit more.

Comment: Either I misread your question because of the earlier (deleted) question, or it's not asking what you want: The earlier question was about manipulating a Java list from Javascript. While Javascript can be on a JSP, it still is in a different execution context. Can you clarify? The way the question is currently phrased, the answer by @Eloytxo is absolutely correct

Answer (score 2):

In your portlet java class, into your render method:

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("attributeName", yourList);
```

In your jsp:

```
<jsp:useBean id="attributeName" type="java.util.List<your.list.class.package>" scope="request"/>
```